# Calculate Previousmonth does not work with Slicer in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

My question might be simple but I've been stuck here for a while.

I'm trying to get the values for current month and previous month. I created 2 Measures to do that (CurrentVal and PreviousVal).

My DAX measures are:

`CurrentVal = SUM ( Database[KPI_Value] )`

```
PreviousVal = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        [CurrentVal]; 
        PREVIOUSMONTH ( DIM_Date[Date] )
    )
```

In the image below, when displayed as a table, you can see it's working fine.

[image]

However, I don't want a table like that, but instead I want a slicer where the user can select the month and he will be able to see the current and previous month values, just like the image below.

The problem, as you can see, is that when I remove the Date from the table and include the slicer, the PreviousVal returns always blank (in this example, it should return 0,44). What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have set up will work, assuming:

1. You have a relationship between the `Date` fields in the `Database` and `DIM_Date` tables
2. Table `DIM_Date` is marked as a date table (Table view, Modelling tab, `Mark as Date Table` )

Here's a worked example: https://excel.solutions/so20181121_previousmonth/

Comment: Thank you so much, Olly! The second step was missing. I set it now as Date Table and it worked. Also very appreciated for the formatting tips. Will try to use this best practice in my codes.

Comment: Struggled with sort of similar issue and that was just because my date table wasn't marked. You are my hero! Thank you.